# How to map a function in Common Lisp?

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, partial-application

I made this function in Common Lisp

```
(defun f (&key n p x)
    (* (combinacion n x) (expt p x) (expt (- 1 p) (- n x))))
```

and it works fine. The thing is that I want to make a function in Common Lisp lake the following Haskell function

```
ff n p x = sum . map (f n p) $ [0 .. x]
```

namley, map the function `f` partially applied to a list.

I made the following function to create the lists

```
(defun range (&key max (min 0) (step 1))
    (loop for n from min to max by step
        collect n))
```

and works fine too, I only need to know how to make the mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common Lisp doesn't have partial applications built in, you just have to write a lambda expression to do what you want.

```
(defun map-f (n p limit)
  (let ((x-list (range :max limit)))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (f :n n :p p :x x)) x-list)))
```

Comment: Common Lisp does not have a `range' function.

Comment: @user1597986 The OP defined it in his question.